# How to position icon position in materialbutton

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I am using Materialbutton from the support library. I want the icon to be to the right of the text?  Ican't seem to find how to do it. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'd however prefer to *let it automatically choose the icon position* depending on the `locale`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the **`app:iconGravity`** attribute.
Use the `app:iconGravity="end"` value.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you used `app:icon=` and it was in the left side, when you make the layout `RTL`, it will show the icon from the `RTL` too.

#### `LTR`:

[image]

**After changing the locale to a `RTL` one**:

[image]

Which seems to be ***a normal behavior*** and it automatically does the job. **However, you better add:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

In your app `build.gradle` dependencies in order to use the latest `MaterialButton` which is better for this purpose.

I was also reading [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) about `MaterialButton` from   `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` which mentioned:

> Add icons to the `start` ***or center of this button*** of this button using
>   the `app:icon`, `app:iconPadding`, `app:iconTint`, `app:iconTintMode` and
>   `app:iconGravity` attributes.

But unfortunately, there weren't any attribute(s) wich would do the trick. Except `app:iconGravity` attribute which has `start` - `textStart`.

## Solution:

Just add:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

To your `MaterialButton`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/guestLogin"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:text="@string/login_as_guest"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_white_24dp" />
```

[image]

---

However, at the meantime, there was-were issue(s) in the documentation which I also [created a pull request](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/219). Hope they'll fix the typo.

> Add icons to the start or center **of this button of this button**

By the way, it could be better if they added `end` in `app:iconGravity=""` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is really bad work around. You are forcing a certain layout which kills the language switching capability of the app .plus the images have to be designed flipped to match this .it is definitely interesting idea but I would stay away from this

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API of `MaterialButton` that allows you to put the icon to the right of the text. This `private` method controls the drawing of the icon:

```
private void updateIcon() {
    if (this.icon != null) {
        this.icon = this.icon.mutate();
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(this.icon, this.iconTint);
        if (this.iconTintMode != null) {
            DrawableCompat.setTintMode(this.icon, this.iconTintMode);
        }

        int width = this.iconSize != 0 ? this.iconSize : this.icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = this.iconSize != 0 ? this.iconSize : this.icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
        this.icon.setBounds(this.iconLeft, 0, this.iconLeft + width, height);
    }

    TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(this, this.icon, (Drawable)null, (Drawable)null, (Drawable)null);
}
```

If you aren't using `app:iconGravity`, though, you can sort of hack around this by manually changing the button's compound drawables after your layout is inflated:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
Drawable d = TextViewCompat.getCompoundDrawablesRelative(b)[0]; // the start drawable
TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(b, null, null, d, null); // move it to the end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion .that's great thank you

Comment: As of release `1.1.0-alpha06` (May 2019), they indeed introduced such a method but with limited gravity options (meaning, nothing on top or bottom). Attempting to  use `TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative` will trigger a `requestLayout` which, at some point, will call `MaterialButton#updateIconPosition` which in turn will call `updateIcon`. The source code of this method has changed since your post and now shows that TOP or BOTTOM gravity are ignored. So, except going back to `1.1.0-alpha05` (from March 2019), I believe there is other way. Am I correct assuming that?

Answer (score 1):

A layout only approach to do this would be:

If you are using the support library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

you can try

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:text="Camera" />
```

---

If you are using the newer material ui library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

you can try

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:text="Camera" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding padding to start and to end. You should be able to position icons with that. E.g:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/fai_btn_dislike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_thumb_down"
                        android:text="@string/fai_dislike"
                        app:icon="@drawable/ic_thumb_down" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for material button with only an icon, just copy this class and use it:

```
/**
 * Created by osapps on 1/20/21.
 *
 * This is a simple class of a material button with just an icon. You can set whatever you want in the xml to use this, but just make sure to also
 * the button's insetTop, insetBottom, insetLeft and insetRight to 0.
 */
class MaterialIconButton : MaterialButton {

    // indications
    private var absPropsSet = false

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        commonInit()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        commonInit()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        commonInit()
    }

    private fun commonInit() {
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        strokeWidth = 0
        stateListAnimator = null
        iconTintMode = PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY
        iconGravity = ICON_GRAVITY_TEXT_START
        iconPadding = 0
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        if(!absPropsSet) {
            iconSize = measuredWidth - paddingStart
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will set absolute properties for the button. Call this function to make the button look exactly as you want.
     * NOTICE: don't forget to set, in the xml, the button's insetTop, insetBottom, insetLeft and insetRight to 0.
     */
    fun setAbsProps(iconSize: Int, @DimenRes paddingRes: Int? = null) {
        absPropsSet = true
        var padding = 0
        paddingRes?.apply { padding = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(paddingRes) }
        setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
        this.iconSize = iconSize
        layoutParams.width = iconSize + padding
        layoutParams.height = iconSize + padding
    }

}
```

**Example of usage:**

```
<com.osfunapps.remoteforsamsung.views.MaterialIconButton
            android:id="@+id/no_ads_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"

            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:padding="12dp"

            android:onClick="onNoAdsClick"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_crown"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.15"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:rippleColor="#F8CE36"
            />
```